# R - order a data.frame by column name AS CHARACTER

Tags: r

I understand that I can order a data.frame as such:

```
test = data.frame(A=c(4,2,4), B=c(8,3,2))
ordered = test[with( test, order(A,B)) , ]
```

But how do I accomplish the same thing when the columns are specified by column name as character variable?  This doesn't seem to work:

```
test = data.frame(A=c(4,2,4), B=c(8,3,2))
cols = c( "A" , "B" )
ordered = test[ with( test, order(cols )) , ]
```

Is there a way to convert "B" to B so that the column is recognized?
I seem to have this problem quite often with functions that take column name inputs. Is there some term to describe this problem-space in R (character identifier versus non-character identifier)?

Comment: I must say I do not understand why this question was down-voted. It seems to be asking for assistance in getting to the "next level" in abstraction. If it's a duplicate then the anonymous voter should step up and show us.

Comment: @DWin - I appreciate the support!  I was confused by the downvote as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try instead:

```
ordered = test[ with( test, order(B)) , ]
```

Or:

```
 ordered2 = test[ order( test[["B"]] ) , ]
```

The second form would allow you to do something like:

```
colnm <- "B"
ordered2 = test[ order(test[[colnm]]) , ]
```

For more than one column to order you need to use do.call (example from the help page):

```
d4 <- data.frame(x = round(   rnorm(100)), y = round(10*runif(100)),
                  z = round( 8*rnorm(100)), u = round(50*runif(100)))
d4s <- d4[ do.call(order, d4[ , c("x", "y") ] ), ]
```

Comment: the intent of my question is to provide "B" (or any other column) by name in a character.  so imagine I had a variable toSort = c("B","A")

Comment: in other words, I don't know ahead of time which columns I want to sort...I want to provide as a parameter/variable.   updated my question to reflect this

Comment: that doesn't seem to work for double-sort, or more generally where lenght of colnm  > 1

Comment: @SFun25: See further addendum.

Comment: brilliant!  It took me a little while to piece out why it works...do.call is really handy.

Comment: Yes,  do.call _is_ handy. Only because I was struggling with another problem that required it, was I able to answer your follow-up quickly. Maybe we will both remember it next time.